# how to start launcher activity after app goes to background?

Tags: android

I want to always start launcher activity after app goes to the background. I tried `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"`  but it not work. How can i do this?  For example i have **A,B,C,D,E,F** activity. **A** is launcher activity.
now i open app so A activity is called then **A>B>C**. now i minimize the application. Now i open application from the icon so app is start from **C** but i want it start from **A** so how can i do this? some said use onResume intent with **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**. but what if i press back button then onResume is called and my app start with A activity.... so it is not work..any solutions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the App is in foreground or is in background and when the application goes to the background state at the same time do some logic that when your application comes to foreground it will always show the root activity.

How you can identify application is in which state is well explained [here](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html)

Comment: i tried this but some reason when i press back button for activity E to D app goes to background. and that should not happen until i reach to root activity. means as per his code my activity stop and run applicationdidenterbackground() method.

Comment: @HarinKaklotar i did tried it for two activities the problem is not occuring on my side and insert the code startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class)); where you are showing toast for activity in foreground in BaseActivity

Comment: @HarinKaklotar it will always show your Root activity when your application will come to foreground

Comment: thank you, it solve my problem and merry Christmas in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

When you start Activity B, use these flags. That way Activity B and C will always be in a separate stack. That means that when someone starts Activity A from the home screen they will see Activity A always.

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Also this might help, you can add this flag to your root Activity.

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"/>
```

Comment: Updated the answer, can you check.

Comment: as per my question i also try that solution

Comment: I've just tried it and it is working for me. I think you shouldn't use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and such with this flag together. Just don't use anything else. Have `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` on your root and it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98956/discussion-between-harin-kaklotar-and-tasomaniac).

Answer (score 0):

This does because device store data about application. For short time data are stored. if you want to start application from rot class. use service with application, so that whenever your application goes in background and pause then choose your action to do that will be easier.