# How to check whether activity is in foreground or background in android?

Tags: android

I have a activity in which in onCreate method I have to check whether activity is in foreground or background .if activity is in foreground then I have to send request to to server and if app goes in background then I have to send that server request through Intent service.How can I do that.

Is there any way if app goes in background stop server request which is in foreground .

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453133/how-to-start-launcher-activity-after-app-goes-to-background/34453412#34453412

Comment: have a look to the link i have provided to you

Answer (score 1):

Try This for check your app is in foreground or not

```
public static boolean isAppInForeground(Context ctx) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx
            .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (services == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (services.size() > 0
            && services.get(0).topActivity
                    .getPackageName()
                    .toString()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(
                            ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                                    .toString())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: but how to make condition for when app goes in background I have to pass IntentService....

Comment: for that you can manage using `WakefulIntentService` for foreground and background both condition.

Answer (score 1):

Track visibility of your application by yourself using **Activity.onPause, Activity.onResume** methods.

**Example Implement custom Application class :**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
  }  

  public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
  }

  public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
  }

  private static boolean activityVisible;
}
```

**Register your application class in `AndroidManifest.xml`**

and then so something like this :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  MyApplication.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  MyApplication.activityPaused();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be you should trigger your service in onStop() call of your activity, as the service gets start your logic in onStatCommand() will be execute and if you want your service should not be dependent on app lifecycle return START_STICKY with in  onStatCommand().

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `Application` class.

```
public class AppSingleton extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

private WeakReference<Context> foregroundActivity;


@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    foregroundActivity=new WeakReference<Context>(activity);
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    String class_name_activity=activity.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    if (foregroundActivity != null && 
            foregroundActivity.get().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(class_name_activity)) {
        foregroundActivity = null;
    }
}

//............................

public boolean isOnForeground(@NonNull Context activity_cntxt) {
    return isOnForeground(activity_cntxt.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}

public boolean isOnForeground(@NonNull String activity_canonical_name) {
    if (foregroundActivity != null && foregroundActivity.get() != null) {
        return foregroundActivity.get().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(activity_canonical_name);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

If you have a reference to the required Activity or using the canonical name of the Activity, you can find out whether it's in the foreground or not. This solution may not be foolproof. Therefore your comments are really welcome.

Comment: Nice one! But don't forget have 
`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)` at `onCreate()` and 
`unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)` at `onTerminate()` of `Application`.

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://github.com/yayaa/TheActivityManager) library. It can ctrack current activity status.